# How do I prove an app is mine?

Tags: licensing, android, legal, software, android-development

So I am in the process of finishing an app (android for now), and I have a doubt about if I should have papers that proof that I made that app.

Its the first time for me to publish an app, and I am concerned about how to prove that I made the app and it belongs to me.

**In other words**

If I came and asked the instagram app developer, prove that you made this app? What would he show me?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

So developers of whatsapp, instagram, skype, ...... have nothing to prove that they made the app? They just publish to the store?

Comment: He would probably tell you to go away. Unless you want to buy the complete rights to the app, why would he or she waste their time for you?

Comment: @gnasher729 the example is just to clarify my question, I mean if authorities asked someone about app ownership what do you show?

Comment: If you own the developer account which can publish the app then you essentially own the app.

Comment: Look into copyright and patent law, or ask a lawyer who specializes in such things for advice.

Comment: And then ask yourself "How do I prove that car is mine?"  Ownership is a very well-established concept.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the car has papers? Its the first time for me to publish an app I need to understand so that I dont face problems later.

Comment: @SomeUser: The software has papers.  Look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=copyrighting+your+program).

Comment: https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ61.pdf

Comment: @RobertHarvey you mean a copyright license of  the source code?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "copyright license."  Read the articles I linked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  if you made an app what would you do before publishing it?

Comment: https://appus.software/blog/how-to-protect-app-ideas-from-being-stolen

Comment: I would copyright it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey copyright is already given once the app is created? You mean that you register the source code with an office?

Comment: The way to do that is described in those articles.  You really should read them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I read them. You mean my papers are the registering of the source code?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you develop an app, register with the app store, fulfill their requirements (whatever those are) and then publish the app, it's going to be very difficult for someone else to come along and claim ownership of your program.

Comment: (unless, of course, they hold the copyright, and not you.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey how would they hold the copyright?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is to show that you are the author of the source code.

Unfortunately, if all you have is your source and your goodwill, another party could come with your source and claim it’s theirs and that you only change the copyright. Then, you’d have to litigate and some very expensive forensic expert could eventually prove it’s yours.

So the key for successfully prove that you’re the author is to have a trustable third party that can confirm that you wrote it first.  An independent repository (e.g GitHub, GitLab & co) can help you because they control their independent timestamps (on your own files you could manipulate time).

Now in most countries, copyright authorities allow you to deposit your source code. It is not mandatory for owning the copyright, but it greatly helps in case of litigation.

***Disclaimer***: I’m not a lawyer, I’m just an author who had some personal experiences in that area. So in case of doubt, the best is to consult a lawyer or a qualified legal expert in your jurisdiction

Comment: How would another party come and with my source if I already registered it with an office?

Comment: I mean is it enough to have the developer account and registering a copyright of the source code with the office?

Comment: @SomeUser There could always be some litigations.  But if as legitimate author you’ve registered the code, I think you have very good cards in hand and the litigator would have to come with strong evidence to challenge your ownership.

Comment: @SomeUser If you want to know more about how this works and the kind of problems you could be confronted with, I can warmly recommend Bob Zeidman’s book “The software IP detective’s handbook”. He gives a brilliant oversight on all aspects and proof issues. He then goes very deep into technical details,maybe beyond what could interest a non-forensic reader. But fir the first part alone it’s a great investment :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. Though I don't know why some people on this site are down voting the question.

Comment: The OP did not ask about sources rather the applications in market.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan intellectual property is a complex matter. And one key aspect is that people make claim about ownership but other make counter claim. In the end there are a lot of legal debates in Courts (out of scope here), but there are also a couple of technical measures about evidence (in scope here). I mentioned this book since there are a lot of unaddressed points in my answer, such as for example if OP has to register every successive version or not (see his comment “is this enough ?”) This reference book adresses these and help to fine tune questions for the lawyer ;-)

Comment: @SomeUser Don’t worry about dv. It’s not personal: some people do not like property issues, some people see this as legal matters (out of scope). I think it’s interesting and relevant here since it is in a way a question related to source code management. I think that it can help  other people here having similar questions.

Comment: @Christophe just wanted to know what you mean by a git repository, you mean local thing or a cloud thing?

Comment: @SomeUser local means that you have control on timestamps and could trick the system to forge evidence in your favor. This means that any evidence coming from this local system has no more value than your own word. If you take a service on the cloud, a third party controls your timestamp. It’s like a witness who would confirm the timing that you claim. Of course the level of trust depends on the trustworthiness of this party and its independence of your own interests.

Comment: @Christophe I read on my office of copyright (in lebanon) that to register a copyright I need to give three copies of my work, and the certificate that is given for me will be sealed and signed and includes 1 copy of the 3 copies. How would a computer program be sealed? Do they mean on a USB stick?

Comment: @Christophe is the copyright certificate a paper or envelope, does a certificate include my work inside it?

Comment: The certificate is usually a paper that states what has been registered. But we are here in a domain that is very country specific. In some countries you can upload to a copyright office, in other countries you may deposit a cdrom or an usb stick at a public agency or a public notary, still other countries do not foresee/require anything but have private companies offering registration services. Here you should really get advise from an IP advisor in your home country.

Comment: Ahh I understand, **I was thinking about this:** if I already post my app to the store (google play store) isn't this considered as a timestamp (so that if someone grabbed the source code it would be useless for them to register the code with an office).

Comment: @SomeUser Sure. But the timestamp is only a proof of the publication by you. You could as well compile and publish open source software on which you have no ownership. So it’s definitively not a proof of ownership. On the other side, if you publish and your source is private and not leaked, it could be sufficient: if you are the only one who has the right source. Up to you to decide on the risks you are ready to take.

Comment: @Christophe last question as I am new to the idea of git stuff, of course you mean first of all to manage my code on github (cloud), and second the github must be made private I guess. But a question comes to my mind is it risky to post my code progress on the cloud? Thanks alot for your replies.

Comment: @SomeUser if you have a private repository and take a serious provider, the risks seem low. The main risk is then that your GIT account gets compromized (e.g. fishing attack, weak password, etc...).  2 factor authentication and some discipline can reduce this risk. There's always the alternative of the public notary if you don't trust the cloud.  Now on the other side, if you do the development on your computer your device is stolen or if you're victim of some ransomware, you may find some additional benefits of having at least your latest commits safe in Microsoft's datacenters !

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways an app developer can prove ownership.

1. App includes link to web site, web site has name and/or photo of the developer.
2. Developer can produce portions of the source code.  (Trivial for open source, much more difficult otherwise)
3. Developer can push requested changes to the app.  (Again, very unlikely unless it's a small app)
4. Trust.  Developer claims authorship, you believe them unless/until you have reason not to.

For what it's worth, the actual act of putting an app onto an app store typically involves encryption.  This means that only the original author (or their delegates) can make changes to the app.

A paper document certifying authorship is pretty much worthless unless it's source code.

Comment: So you are saying that no need for legal stuff, I just publish to the store?

Comment: If the app became popular, and authorities asked me about the app ownership, or maybe someone wants to buy the app later on, what do I show?

Answer (score 2):

You either are the owner, or you’re not. It only matters if someone else claims to be the owner and complains. Like if I complained to Apple or Google that the app is really mine, then I and you would have both to prove ownership - obviously only one of us can prove it.

If it went to court, it would be best if you had not only the source code, but also for example git repositories for the whole development time. You should have that automatically, but it would be a huge amount of work to forge it.

To the comment: No, everything you write is automatically your copyright (unless you write it as an employee). You don't have to contact any authorities for that or take any action. What I said was that if you developed an app over a year, and you have a git repository that started empty a year ago, and code was added every day, sometimes with bugs, then later with fixes for those bugs, that repository is pretty strong evidence that *you* wrote the code. And not someone who managed to make a copy of your source code, or not even that.

Comment: You mean I must copyright the source code of the app, all java classes and xml files?

Answer (score 1):

[Code signing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing) is the only technically guaranteed way to proof your ownership for an app. When you publish an app in Appstore or PlayStore, your app needs to be signed with a developers signing certificate with your private key, name of the company and other related information. All the members who have that private key with them can claim as the owner of the app. For example, Signing process for Android has been described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing). Moreover, most of the modern IDEs have the ability to do those kind of signing job for you in implicitly.

Now, when you need to claim for an apps ownership, just [extract](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Project-META-INF-Files-Digest-Signature-and-Certificate.html) your certificate from the product and show your information to the person you are proving to.

Comment: so the private key is found in the developers account?

Comment: No. Developer can keep it anywhere he wants privately. Most of the cases in developers PC/storage, i.e. Keychain in case of iOS. @SomeUser

Comment: Interesting. But code signing does not prove ownership: I could compile and code sign any project if I have the source! The author quality that matters is source code ownership. The problem is then not the signing but the trusted time. A malicious opponent could copy the source, replace the copyright notice, and sign it on a machine with a wrong time that place it before your signature. Management of evidence is a complex issue. Third parties offer this kind of service. Maybe blockchain could be an option as well in the future.